# WooCommerce variables in Webhooks

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm using WooCommerce Bookings & WooCommerce Vendors plugins and I want to get the booking & vendor information in a Webhook (on order confirmation) along with the order information to send to a 3rd party.

Currently, the Order Created webhook only contains the product order details (not Booking & Vendor).

I've been searching a lot for different answers and trying to go down a few different paths (inputting into the webhook directly vs add_order_item_meta.

Here's one way I've tried:

```
add_action('woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', 'add_order_item_meta', 10, 2);

function add_order_item_meta($item_id, $values) {

    // Get order id to get booking details

    global $post;
    $order = wc_get_order( $post->ID );
    $order_id = $order->get_id();
    $items = $order->get_items();

    $booking_data = new WC_Booking_Data_Store();
    $booking_ids = $booking_data->get_booking_ids_from_order_id( $order_id );

    if ( is_array( $booking_ids ) && count( $booking_ids ) > 0 ) {
        foreach ( $booking_ids as $booking_id ) {
            $booking = get_wc_booking( $booking_id );
      $booking_product = $booking->get_product()->get_title()
            $booker_start_date = $booking->get_start_date();
            $booker_end_date = $booking->get_end_date();    

      if ( ! empty( $booking_id ) ){
                woocommerce_add_order_item_meta($item_id, "Booking Title", $booking_product);
            }
      if ( ! empty( $booking_id ) ){
                woocommerce_add_order_item_meta($item_id, "Booking ID", $booking_id);
            }
            if ( ! empty( $booker_start_date ) ){
                woocommerce_add_order_item_meta($item_id, "Booking Start Date", $booker_start_date);
            }
            if ( ! empty( $booker_end_date ) ){
                woocommerce_add_order_item_meta($item_id, "Booking End Date", $booker_end_date);
            }
        }
    }
```

The output of this is a large array of bookings that have been made under the user, so it seems the $order_id isn't passing into the $bookings_id properly.

Also, for some reason, I haven't been able to get `$items = $order->get_items();` as I keep getting `Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_items() on boolean`. I want to use this to get the vendor email.

I'd prefer a webhook rather than using the API because it looks like you can't filter through booking in the API (ie you have to fetch all bookings).

Happy to get any guidance on the best way to approach it.

Thanks, Andy

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up creating a hook based on payment confirmed.

It might not be the best way, but it's piping the info through based on the correct trigger.

```
add_action('woocommerce_webhook_payload', 'my_woocommerce_webhook_payload', 1, 4);

function my_woocommerce_webhook_payload($payload, $resource, $resource_id, $id) {
    // Get Order details via order id
    $payload['order_id'] = $resource_id;
    $order_id = $resource_id;
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $order_data = $order->get_data();

    // Get booking ids from Order
    $booking_ids = WC_Booking_Data_Store::get_booking_ids_from_order_id( $order_id );
    $payload['booking_ids'] = $booking_ids;



    // Add relevant information to each booking
    if ( is_array( $booking_ids ) && count( $booking_ids ) > 0 ) {
        foreach ( $booking_ids as $key=>$booking_id ) {
            // Fetch booking details
            $booking = get_wc_booking( $booking_id );
            $booking_product = $booking->get_product()->get_title();
            $booker_start_date = $booking->get_start_date();
            $booker_end_date = $booking->get_end_date();

            $booking_details = [];
            // Add booking details

            $payload["bookings"][$key] = $booking_details;      
        }
    }

    return $payload;
}
```